# Failing to change user_id from original owner into another existing user

Tags: quickblox

I have a need to transfer a CustomObject record from one user to another. With permissions I can share them, but for some reason I fail to edit the user_id with JSON with REST, but I can do it from the Admin panel.

Is it possible to edit the user_id to another existing user, when logged in as the "original" owner?

Thanks,
Niittis

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it because **user_id** - this is ID of record's creator. Only Admin can do this via Admin panel.

Why do you need this ?

Comment: Ok, I learned that by try and fail. I needed this in case where a "coach" created a plan to his "client". I wanted the full ownership to transfer to the Client with Coach able to modify the plan. 

The workaround was to make the Client to create a clone of the plan.